# browser-sync stream svg when using svg symbols

Tags: svg, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I'm trying to add browser-sync to an existing gulp setup. In my gulpfile I have a task that takes svgs in a folder and creates a single svg file with a `<symbol>` for each individual svg file.

In the html individual svg's are used like so where `SpriteFile.svg` is the file that contains the `<symbol>`s and `icon-name` is the `id` of one of those `<symbol>` elements.

```
<svg width="16" height="16">
    <use xlink:href="/SpriteFile.svg#icon-name"></use>
</svg>
```

This all works fine but I cannot get browser-sync to update the icons. My task looks like this

```
gulp.src(`./Icons/*.svg`)
    .pipe( svgstore( { inlineSvg: true } ) )
    .pipe( rename( 'SpriteFile.svg' ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( './' ) )
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
```

In the browser-sync console I can see that it picks up the change. And I can see in devtools that the websocket was delivered to the browser. But the browser does not update the icon(s).

I imagine this is because the path it is trying to update is `SpriteFile.svg` but on the page it is referenced as `SpriteFile.svg#icon-name` and it thinks those are not the same files. How can I tell browser-sync to update all paths that match `SpriteFile.svg` including the symbol suffix?